# SDK emulator directory is missing in Android Studio on window

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

Help Me
How i can to fix it?

The error mesage:

[image: How i can to fix it?]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not too late to give a solution to this issue,
In my case I changed the regional settings to English language.